# Refactor my viewholder class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a recycler list which holds many different types of item views. It is quite easy to use databinding without necessary to declare the layout and assignment in the viewholder, however I end up with many biloplate code to just create the different viewholders with databinding, is there a way to get rid of them?

```
class ViewHolder1 private constructor(
    val binding: ViewHolder1LayoutBinding
): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    companion object {
        fun create(parent: ViewGroup): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val binding = ViewHolder1LayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder1(binding)
        }
    }

    fun bind(viewModel: ViewHolder1ViewModel) {
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

kotlin supports view binding so no need to do other stuffs for binding view.
Just follow steps and you will able to access view by its **id** defined in xml layout.

In app level gradle add following

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

**Import view**

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout_file>.view.*
```

Just check this class for **demo**

```
class NotificationHolder(itemView: View?, listener: NotificationItemListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    init {
        itemView?.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onNotificationItemClicked(adapterPosition)
        }
    }

    fun bind(notificationModel: NotificationModel) {
        val titleArray = notificationModel.title.split("#".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
        itemView.tvNotificationTitle.text = titleArray[0]
        itemView.tvNotificationDetails.text = notificationModel.message
        itemView.tvNotificationTime.text = notificationModel.formattedTime
        Glide.with(itemView.context).load(ServiceHandler.BASE_URL + notificationModel.icon).dontAnimate().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).error(R.drawable.user_default_logo).into(itemView.imageView)
        if (CommonUtils.lastNotificationTime < notificationModel.date) {
            itemView.card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
        } else {
            itemView.card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f2f2f2"))
        }
    }
}
```

In adapter you can override

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return if (viewType == 0 || viewType == 3) {
            NotificationHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.item_notification, parent, false), this)
        } else {
            NotificationListHeaderHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.item_notification_header, parent, false))
        }
    }

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        (holder as? NotificationHolder)?.bind(notificationList[position])
        (holder as? NotificationListHeaderHolder)?.bind(notificationList[position])

    }
```